# To compute complex derivatives Leibniz style

Tags: complex-analysis

Here's a semi-serious question.

[Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/798570/8157) we have introduced the differential forms 
$$\tag{1}
\begin{array}{cc}
dz=dx+idy, & d\overline{z}=dx-idy,
\end{array}
$$
Now let us look at this formula, familiar from complex variable theory:
$$\tag{2}\begin{array}{cc}
\frac{d}{dz}=\frac{1}{2}\left( \frac{\partial}{\partial x} - i \frac{\partial}{\partial y} \right), & \frac{d}{d\overline{z}}=\frac{1}{2}\left( \frac{\partial}{\partial x}+i\frac{\partial}{\partial y}\right)
\end{array}
$$

> **Question**. Can we recover (2) from (1) with a formal computation that treats $dx$ and $dy$ as infinitesimals?

Inserting blindly $(1)$ into the left hand sides of $(2)$ we get 
$$\begin{array}{cc}
\frac{d}{dz}=\frac{d}{dx+idy},&\frac{d}{d\overline{z}}=\frac{d}{dx-idy}
\end{array} $$ 
but how to move on from there?

Comment: What's so wrong about this question, down voter?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You shouldn't view $\dfrac{d}{dx}$ as the quotient of $d$ (whatever that would be) and $dx$ but rather as the dual of $dx$ in the sense that

$$
df = \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\,dx + \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\,dy.
$$
Similarly,
$$
df = \frac{\partial f}{\partial z}\,dz + \frac{\partial f}{\partial \bar z}\,d\bar z.
$$
Here, $df$ is the *exterior derivative* of $f$.

Equating the two and using $dz = dx + i\,dy$ and $d\bar z = dx - i\,dy$ you get
\begin{align}
\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\,dx + \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\,dy &=
\frac{\partial f}{\partial z}\,dz + \frac{\partial f}{\partial \bar z}\,d\bar z \\
&= \frac{\partial f}{\partial z}\,(dx + i\,dy) + \frac{\partial f}{\partial \bar z}\,(dx -i\,dy) \\
&= \left( \frac{\partial f}{\partial z} + \frac{\partial f}{\partial \bar z} \right)\,dx 
+ i\left( \frac{\partial f}{\partial z} - \frac{\partial f}{\partial \bar z} \right)\,dy.
\end{align}

I.e.
$$
\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} = \frac{\partial f}{\partial z} + \frac{\partial f}{\partial \bar z}
$$
and
$$
\frac1i \frac{\partial f}{\partial y} = \frac{\partial f}{\partial z} - \frac{\partial f}{\partial \bar z}.
$$
Adding and subtracting these two equations finally gives you
\begin{align}
\frac{\partial f}{\partial z} &= 
\frac12 \left( \frac{\partial f}{\partial x} + \frac1i \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\right)
= \frac12 \left( \frac{\partial f}{\partial x} -i \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\right) \\
\frac{\partial f}{\partial \bar z} &= 
\frac12 \left( \frac{\partial f}{\partial x} - \frac1i \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\right)
= \frac12 \left( \frac{\partial f}{\partial x} +i \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\right) \\
\end{align}
as expected.

Comment: Good answer, and actually this is not hand-waving at all.

Comment: Here's a hand-waving version of your argument ( :-) ): one could write 
$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}=\frac{\partial f}{\partial z}\frac{\partial z}{\partial x} + \frac{\partial f}{\partial \overline{z}}\frac{\partial \overline{z}}{\partial x}, $$and $$\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}=\frac{dx+idy}{dx}=1, $$
while 
$$\frac{\partial \overline{z}}{\partial x}=\frac{dx-idy}{\partial x}=1.$$
The same for $\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}$. And then one finishes like you did. :-)

Comment: I just found that the very same technique you described here is used in the [Wolfram MathWorld page on spherical coordinates](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SphericalCoordinates.html) to express Cartesian partial derivatives in terms of spherical partial derivatives. (It's at the very end of the page). Nice to know